# Recyclerview, карточка за карточкой

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-viewpager

В своём приложении я реализовал горизонтальный скролл таких же карточек, как показано на скриншоте, но проблема в том, что они быстро скроллятся. Как сделать так, чтобы при свайпе происходило перелистывание на одну следующую карточку, а не моталось до конца списка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам тут больше подойдёт `ViewPager`.

Comment: @eugeneek Кстати, я не подумал об этом. Спасибо!